# JavaScript code failing on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In my JavaScript program, I have:

```
const myFunction = async function (input) {
 // do stuff
}
```

It runs fine on Windows 10. But same code gives error on AWS EC2 instance:

```
const myFunction = async function (input) {

SyntaxError: Unexpected token function

at createScript (vm.js:56:10)

at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
```

What do I need to do here?

Comment: What nodejs versions you have on both machines? How do you run the script?

Comment: On windows 10, its v8.10.0. On EC2, its v6.13.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async` support was added in nodejs v7.6

Given you're running nodejs v6.13.0 - that's why it fails

Solution: upgrade your nodejs on the target server or don't use `async`.

Answer (score 1):

The keywords async/await were introduced in ES2017.

You may need to transpile your ES2017 code into a syntax that your EC2 Node version understands. If your EC2 is not running Node v7.6 or greater (`node -v`), then async/await will not work out of the box.

Transpile your js with [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or upgrade node to the latest [LTS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on your EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check for . babelrc 
It must be missing